# Sync two databases by CDC component in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am going to keep two databases sync with each other by using CDC component in SSIS (For VS 2013). So far I have created a SSIS Package which transfers all data from one to the other. However, I have some difficulties with incremental loading of records.

The problem is I have about 30 tables in my database. Although I can incrementally move data for a single table like the following, but it is really time-consuming to create this process for each individual table. Is there any workaround to do the same procedure for all tables automatically?

[image]
***Figure 1: Incremental loading for one table.***

[image]
***Figure 2: For each table I have to write Update and Delete commands manually as depicted.***

Comment: Afraid there isn't! Does only one of the database copies change, with the other being only changed to match the first?

Comment: Yes. The second Database is for the reporting purpose only. So there is no change in that except the changes pushing from the first database. I had used Transactional Replication to accomplish this task but it was too frustrating to work with (at least for me) so I want to try another approach.

Comment: I was going to suggest replication. It seems to work well for others - perhaps you could post a question about problems you had with it?

Comment: Have you looked at BIML? It excels at writing SSIS packages where there is some degree of redundancy in the components. Which seems to match your scenario (so the same basic transform over a set of tables).

Comment: @BenThul unfortunatly not! I have no idea about that. Would you please tell me how can it help? Or give me a reference related to my scenario?

Comment: Oh the places you'll go. :) You'll need to get BIDSHelper from codeplex. After that, give http://bimlscript.com/ a look. They have plenty of tutorials, etc to help. But I've used BIML for a very similar project to great success. My advice would be to start slow (i.e. get it to reproduce your current flow for one table) and then abstract it to go across all the tables you need it to.

As to how it might help, BIML is very good at automating the creation of SSIS packages. You can also query your database from within the BIMLscript, so you can use data queries to drive the logic.